# VS 2017 Team Explorer GIT "Push Branch" Grayed out

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

VS 2017 Team Explorer GIT "Push Branch" is Grayed out for me. I create a new local branch from a remote branch with no tracking and then I try to create a remote branch with the same name as the local branch by clicking on "Push Branch". Why would this option be grayed out for me?

Answer (score 2):

I place it here, as someone like me will search again for that, I have resolved by doing branch Rebase. Commit your changes before. And then:

[image: Rebase window]

[image: Result]

Probably it happens after you have manipulated remote repository settings.

In another case i just deleted all origins and created them again

[image]

Another addition. Be sure that you always has remote with "origin" name, that's another problem I faced right now, during migration of my projects.

Comment: My remote was named something else. When I changed it to origin I was able to push changes.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Rename one of your remotes to "origin" with this command:

```
git remote rename your-remote-name-goes-here origin
```

Then you should be able to Push, Pull, and Fetch in Visual Studio. These options will no longer be grayed out.

Answer (score -2):

The direct way to push a new created local branch to VSTS git repo by VS is clicking **push branch** button directly on local branch (don’t need to create the same branch in remote manually).

Detail steps as: VS -> Team explorer -> Branches -> right click the local branch -> Push branch -> then the local branch is pushed to remote.

[image]

Since you have already created the same branch on remote, you can fetch first and then push:
Team explorer ->Sync -> Fetch -> push.

[image]

---

when you clone the remote repo (no matter on VSTS or bitbucket) again, and siwtch to the new created branch, the branch willexist in `remotes/origin`, so you can push directly.
[image]

Comment: Hi Marina - MSFT, The repo is in Bitbucket server. When I try to push branch the option is grayed out. When I installed Bitbucket extension for VS, logged into the server and cloned from there the push branch was no more grayed out. What could be happening? Regards

Comment: If you cloned this repo and then checkout to the new created branch, you can commit your changes and push directly. I added it in the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks Marina - MSFT. I clone a remote branch without tracking, name it differently and the resulting local branch I want to push to the remote branch (after applying my changes). Push Branch helps me do that. But like I had mentioned earlier it is grayed out. I am unable to understand why that is the case. Will it be some authentication issue?

Comment: If you have local branch which name (`branch1`) is different from the branch you created on remote (`branch2`), just like the first situation you asked: right click the local branch -> **push branch** to push it to remote branch `branch1`. If you want to push the changes from local `branch1` to remote `branch2`, you can execute by command line: `git checkout branch1` and `git push origin branch2`.

Comment: "Push Branch" is greyed out on my context menu.